# wordpress custom post category filter

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, taxonomy

I'm trying to display only certain categories for a custom post called portfolio in my portfolio template page. I am amble to display only 1 category by the slug but I need to display more than 1 and I'll like to know if there's a way to filter the categories by their ID.

CODE

```
global $wp_query;

$portfolio_items = $sd_data['portfolio_items']; // Get Items per Page Value
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array(
            'post_type'         => 'portfolio',

            'posts_per_page'    => $portfolio_items,
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'orderby'           => 'date',
            'paged'             => $paged
        );

// Only pull from selected taxonomy
$selected_taxonomies = rwmb_meta('sd_portfolio-taxonomies', 'type=checkbox_list');

    if($selected_taxonomies && $selected_taxonomies[0] == 0) {
        unset($selected_taxonomies[0]);
        }

    if($selected_taxonomies){
        $args['tax_query'][] = array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'portfolio_filter',
            'field'     => 'ID',
            'terms'     =>  $selected_taxonomies 
        );
    }

    $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
query_posts( array( 'portfolio_filter' => 'extra', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
```

As you can see I can only filter the category extra but I need to filter more than 1 and I'll like to know if there's a way to filter the categories by their IDs